# crystal report are not displaying my records

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports-2011

I have sap Crystal Report 13 in my application, It is working fine in simple tables, But in specific scenario like: I have a table which loaded via store procedure when i load this table, then report going to be called and after showing the report i clean the table by using delete query. If i comment that query report show record otherwise empty report appears. Please see my code:

```
private void btnPreview_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsErrorFound() == false)
        {
            MyResources.WaitDialogCreate("Loading....");
            string FormulaString = "";
            string Parameters = "";

            //***** Insert Data in table naamed tblReportTrialBalanceWith (With and Without Of Opening Bal) FROM Store Procedure
            string Qry = "INSERT INTO tblReportTrialBalanceWithOpening EXEC [spTrialBalance] @MinFY = '" + GlobalVriables.FYearDateStart.Year.ToString() + "'," +
            "@MaxFY = '" + GlobalVriables.FYearDateEnd.Year.ToString() + "'," +
            "@DateFrom = '" + MyResources.getDateForDB(dteFromDate.Text.Trim()) + "'," +
            "@DateTo = '" + MyResources.getDateForDB(dteToDate.Text.Trim()) + "'," +
            "@FromCode = '" + lkpFromCode.Text.Trim() + "'," +
            "@ToCode = '" + lkpToCode.Text.Trim() + "'," +
            "@Category = '" + rdoAccCategory.Text.Trim() + "'";

            DatabaseHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Qry);

            if (chkWithOutOB.Checked == true)
            {

                //************* Parameters
                Parameters = "CompanyName=" + GlobalVriables.CompanyName + 
                    "&StartingDate=" + dteFromDate.Text +
                    "&EndingDate=" + dteToDate.Text +
                    "&Category=" + (rdoAccCategory.SelectedIndex == 0 ? "All Categories" : rdoAccCategory.Text.Trim()) + 
                    "&FYear=[" + GlobalVriables.FYearDateStart.Year + "-" + GlobalVriables.FYearDateEnd.Year + "]";
                switch (rdoAccCategory.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Parameters = Parameters + "&ReportCase=0";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Parameters = Parameters + "&ReportCase=2";
                        break;
                    default:
                        Parameters = Parameters + "&ReportCase=1";
                        break;
                }
                MyResources.ViewReport("RptTrialBalanceWithOutOB.rpt", FormulaString, Parameters);
                ////***** Clean up tblReportTrialBalanceWithOpening for Future use.
                //Qry = "DELETE FROM tblReportTrialBalanceWithOpening";
                //DatabaseHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Qry);
            }
            else
            {
                //************* Parameters
                Parameters = "CompanyName=" + GlobalVriables.CompanyName + 
                    "&StartingDate=" + dteFromDate.Text.Trim() + 
                    "&EndingDate=" + dteToDate.Text +
                    "&Category=" + (rdoAccCategory.SelectedIndex == 0 ? "All Categories" : rdoAccCategory.EditValue.ToString()) + 
                    "&FYear=[" + GlobalVriables.FYearDateStart.Year + "-" + GlobalVriables.FYearDateEnd.Year + "]";
                switch (rdoAccCategory.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Parameters = Parameters + "&ReportCase=0";
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Parameters = Parameters + "&ReportCase=2";
                        break;
                    default:
                        Parameters = Parameters + "&ReportCase=1";
                        break;
                }
                MyResources.ViewReport("RptTrialBalance.rpt", FormulaString, Parameters);
                ////***** Clean up tblReportTrialBalanceWithOpening for Future use.
                //Qry = "DELETE FROM tblReportTrialBalanceWithOpening";
                //DatabaseHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Qry);
            }
            MyResources.WaitDialogDispose();
            //***** Clean up tblReportTrialBalanceWithOpening for Future use.
            Qry = "DELETE FROM tblReportTrialBalanceWithOpening";
            DatabaseHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Qry);
        }

    }
```

you can see my delete query if i comment it. My report shows record. delete query is must in my case. So please help me i am total scattered. One more thing remember my app was upgraded from 2010 to 2012 visual studio successfully expect this problem.